# android contact list create groups

Tags: android

I am working on a contact list project and so far i can add,modify delete  and search for a contact.and when i click on a contact i cand call him send email or sms.I have one table named contacts in my database with folowing fields id,name,phone number and email.

What i need to do next is create groups and add contacts to this groups.
Can you give me some ideas how to do this.I think i should do one more table in my database named groups for example  which would have fields: group id ,group name ,contacts id.And i need to make a join to show contacts for a group.

Is this posible to create 2 tables in android database ?can you give me any example(tutorial on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to implement is to imitate Android Contacts database.Look at the Android contacts database itself.Its a bit complex but exactly what you can refer as to what tables and columns you might need in your app.
You can access that database by pulling out the file data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts.db  from Eclipse File Explorer view in DDMS perspective when your Android emulator is running. The file name can also be contact2.db.
Then you can view the DB tables using "Sqlite DB Browser" which can be downloaded [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/).